# Redirecting all subdomains to a domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-domain-access

I am having an issue with one of my sites where I need to redirect all subdomains to the main domain name. I have a Drupal site set up that shares content between 2 domains (using the Domain module). Here is basically what is going on.

In my .htaccess file I have these rules..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects any subdomain to mydomain.com, which is great!

The problem is that I have another domain (myotherdomain.com) which uses the same Drupal site to share content with via the Domain module.

With that .htaccess rule in place when I go to `myotherdomain.com` it is redirecting to `mydomain.com` which I do not want to happen. Is there any way that I can stop that from happening?

To recap:

1. *anything*.mydomain.com needs to redirect to mydomain.com
2. any traffic to myotherdomain.com needs to stay at myotherdomain.com and not get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another exclusion condition for your other domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myotherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This way, any request for "myotherdomain.com" won't get redirect, and any request for "mydomain.com" won't get redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Any RewriteCond before a RewriteRule will be applied. Have you tried adding simply `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myotherdomain\.com$ [NC]`?